# Ошибки в PyQt5, с QLineEdit

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlineedit

Занимался разработкой простенькой программы, но появилась ошибка:

> result = sqrt(self.firstNumber ** 2 + self.secondNumber ** 2)
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'QLineEdit' and 'int'

Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку.
Заранее спасибо!

**main.py**

```
from sys import *
from math import *

import ui
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(argv)
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = ui.Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(window)

class Main:
    def __init__(self, firstNumber, secondNumber):
        self.firstNumber = firstNumber
        self.secondNumber = secondNumber

    def result(self):
        result = sqrt(self.firstNumber ** 2 + self.secondNumber ** 2)

main = Main(ui.lineEdit, ui.lineEdit_2)
main.result()

window.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

**ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(265, 167)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 50, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 101, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 101, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 80, 47, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 80, 111, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 265, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Окно"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Тык"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "первая дистанция"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вторая дистанция"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Итог: "))
        self.lineEdit_3.setInputMask(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Спросите, если что-то не понятно.

```
from math import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(265, 167)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 50, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 101, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 101, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 80, 47, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 80, 111, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 265, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Окно"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Тык"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "первая дистанция"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вторая дистанция"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Итог: "))
# ???        self.lineEdit_3.setInputMask(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.lineEdit_3.setReadOnly(True)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.result)

    def result(self):
        try:
            firstNumber = float(self.lineEdit.text())
            secondNumber = float(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        
            if firstNumber and secondNumber:
                result = sqrt(float(firstNumber) ** 2 + float(secondNumber) ** 2)
                self.lineEdit_3.setText(f'{result:.2f}')
        except:
            pass
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @VpFont что не так?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self, firstNumber, secondNumber):
        self.firstNumber = int(firstNumber.text()) # Получение данных из виджета
        self.secondNumber = int(secondNumber.text())

    def result(self):
        result = sqrt(self.firstNumber ** 2 + self.secondNumber ** 2)
```